# JS - cannot read property value of null

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to check if the user entered a right string in real time in a HTML Form
Here's the HTML

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input class="form-control" name="nbequipement" id="nbequipement" placeholder="" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Creer le tableau" onclick="GenerateTable()" />
  </div>
```

Here's the javascript that creates the table:

```
function GenerateTable()
{
    var edValue = document.getElementById("nbequipement");
    var s = edValue.value;
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.className = "table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" ;
    table.id = "table";
    //CREATION DE L'ENTETE
    var tableHeader = table.insertRow(-1);
    var header1 = document.createElement("TH");
    header1.innerHTML = "Nom d'hote";
    //CREATION DE CHAQUE ROW DU TABLEAU
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= s ; i++) {
        //CREATION DE LA LIGNE
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        //CREATION DE CHAQUE CELLULES
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell1.className = "col-md-1";
        cell1.id='container'+ i +'hostname'+ i + '';
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input class="input-sm" id="hostname' + i + '" placeholder="" type="text" onKeyPress="checkHostname('+cell1.id+', hostname'+i+')" onKeyUp="checkHostname('+cell1.id+', hostname'+i+')">' ;
    }

    var body = document.getElementById("tableSpace");
    body.innerHTML = "";
    body.appendChild(table);
```

You can see that in the InnerHTML of "cell1", there are two listeners : onKeyPress & onKeyDown

And when the function "checkhostname()" is called, I have this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of nullcheckHostname @ template.js:128onkeyup @ templates.php:1
```

Here's the function :

```
function checkHostname(containerId, elementId) {
    var textContainer = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var texte = textContainer.value;
    //CHECK THE VARIABLE "texte"
    //var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
}
```

I don't understand why this error is generated. Some people spoke about the code beeing executed before it is written, but it seems impossible in this case.

Comment: `onKeyPress="checkHostname('+cell1.id+', hostname'+i+')" onKeyUp`

You need to add the `elementId`  (`hostname'+i+'`) in quotes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cristy's comment is your answer. Where you have:

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<input ... onKeyPress="checkHostname('+cell1.id+', hostname'+i+')" ...>' ;
```

if *cell1.id* is say "foo" and *i* is say 0, then it will be seen as markup like:

```
<input ... onKeyPress="checkHostname(foo0, hostname0)" ...>
```

so *foo0* and *hostname0* will be treated as variable names, not strings. So you need to wrap them in quotes, e.g.

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<input ... onKeyPress="checkHostname(\''+cell1.id+'\', \'hostname'+i+'\')" ...>' ;
```

so it is seen as:

```
<input ... onKeyPress="checkHostname('foo0', 'hostname0')" ...>'
```

Of course this still depends on elements with those IDs (well, the correct IDs) existing in the document when the code is run. You say that is so, so it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Your element doesn't exists by some reason. But you can avoid the error:

```js
function checkHostname(containerId, elementId) {
    var textContainer = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(textContainer) {
      var texte = textContainer.value;
    }
}
```